# Edit a script to include checkbox to order total

Tags: javascript, checkbox, sum

I've got this script:

```
//CODE BELOW THIS POINT IS NOT MINE//

/* This script is Copyright (c) Paul McFedries and 
Logophilia Limited (http://www.mcfedries.com/).
Permission is granted to use this script as long as 
this Copyright notice remains in place.*/

function CalculateTotal(frm) {
var order_total = 0

// Run through all the form fields
for (var i=0; i < frm.elements.length; ++i) {

    // Get the current field
    form_field = frm.elements[i]

    // Get the field's name
    form_name = form_field.name

    // Is it a "product" field?
    if (form_name.substring(0,4) == "PROD") {

        // If so, extract the price from the name
        item_price = parseFloat(form_name.substring(form_name.lastIndexOf("_") + 1))

        // Get the quantity
        item_quantity = parseInt(form_field.value)

        // Update the order total
        if (item_quantity >= 0) {
            order_total += item_quantity * item_price

    //My attempt at updating order total for checkbox
           if(document.checkbox.select[i].checked)  
        {
            order_total = item_price

       }

        }
    }
}

// Display the total rounded to two decimal places
frm.TOTAL.value = round_decimals(order_total, 2)
}

function round_decimals(original_number, decimals) {
var result1 = original_number * Math.pow(10, decimals)
var result2 = Math.round(result1)
var result3 = result2 / Math.pow(10, decimals)
return pad_with_zeros(result3, decimals)
 }

function pad_with_zeros(rounded_value, decimal_places) {

// Convert the number to a string
var value_string = rounded_value.toString()

// Locate the decimal point
var decimal_location = value_string.indexOf(".")

// Is there a decimal point?
if (decimal_location == -1) {

    // If no, then all decimal places will be padded with 0s
    decimal_part_length = 0

    // If decimal_places is greater than zero, tack on a decimal point
    value_string += decimal_places > 0 ? "." : ""
}
else {

    // If yes, then only the extra decimal places will be padded with 0s
    decimal_part_length = value_string.length - decimal_location - 1
}

// Calculate the number of decimal places that need to be padded with 0s
var pad_total = decimal_places - decimal_part_length

if (pad_total > 0) {

    // Pad the string with 0s
    for (var counter = 1; counter <= pad_total; counter++) 
        value_string += "0"
    }
return value_string
}
//CODE ABOVE THIS POINT IS NOT MINE//
```

and you define the price of an item and it's id with this:

```
    <input type="text" name="PROD_CH_35.00" onChange="CalculateTotal(this.form)">
```

and this is the checkbox function code:

```
function totalcheckbox() {
document.checkbox.TOTAL.value = ''; //I set the value of all the checkboxes equal to nothing
var total = 0;
//For loop iterates through all the checkboxes. ++ adds one each time to i.
for (i=0;i<document.checkbox.select.length;i++) {
      if (document.checkbox.select[i].checked) {
        total = total + parseInt(document.checkbox.select[i].value); //take whatever they selected and make it into an integer
      }
    }
document.checkbox.TOTAL.value = total; //total value box equal to the sum
}
```

and my checkboxes are like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="select" value="15" onchange="totalcheckbox()">
```

The problem I'm having is two of the fields are checkboxes. I want it so when I select those checkboxes it will add to the order total. When I deselect the checkboxes, it will subtract by the price of the checkboxes.

So for example, I could have a checkbox like this:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="PROD_CH_15.00" value="15" onchange="totalcheckbox()">
```

By itself, the function for the checkboxes work itself to add a total and the order total functions work as well. The biggest issue is editing the order total script so that the checkboxes will change the total price the same way if you were to enter a quantity in a textbox it would update the total.

Here's the JS Fiddle for the working Checkbox Code: http://jsfiddle.net/7uzr4/

Here's the JS Fiddle for the Order Total Code: http://jsfiddle.net/X2wMR/

How do I combine those two codes so that the checkbox code will also add to the Order Total?

Comment: A fiddle would be great, it's a long question...

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `item_quantity` based on the field type. Your current `CalculateFunction` should work with just a minor change:

```
// Get the quantity
if(form_field.type == 'checkbox') {
    // Will be 0 for unchecked, 1 for checked
    item_quantity = form_field.checked;
} else {
    item_quantity = parseInt(form_field.value, 10);           
}
```

Then just call the same function from the checkboxes' `onchange`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="PROD_CH_15.00" value="15" onchange="CalculateTotal(this.form)">
```

[Working version on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X2wMR/1/)